# how to implement a custom QPlainTextEdit widget

Tags: c++, qt, qtwidgets

I'm trying to implement a custom `QPlainTextEdit` that takes a buffer say `QString` for now, I'm trying to look at [QPlaintTextEdit](https://codebrowser.dev/qt6/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qplaintextedit.h.html) source code and I'm not getting it

I Tried implementing it on my own the only thing I could implement is drawing Text into the screen

```cpp
class TextArea : public QAbstractScrollArea
{
public:
    TextArea(QWidget *parent)
        : QAbstractScrollArea(parent)
    {
    }

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) override
    {
        QPainter painter(this);
        painter.fillRect(event->rect(), Qt::black);

        painter.drawText(event->rect(), Qt::AlignLeft, buffer);
    }

private:
    QString buffer;
};
```

is there is any reference or tutorial to how it's built

Comment: What should you custom widget do, what the Qt widget can't do? The Qt widget has a buffer [plainText](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qplaintextedit.html#plainText-prop) of type QString for it's content. Writing a custom edit is a complex thing.

Comment: because of copying look what I'm trying to do is editing files if I did it the way you with `setPlainTextEdit(QString)`  it will take so much performance to copy and paste every time the user tries to save big files unless there is some way to use std::move + having my own thing makes it easier for me customize later on for say syntax highlighting

Comment: QString doesn't copy the data by copying the object. It implements [copy-on-write](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/implicit-sharing.html) which makes copying similar efficient as moving. As long as you don't keep the QString object outside the QPlainTextEdit class, there will never be made a copy of it's data. Also you may take a look at QSyntaxHighlighter. If this doesn't fit your needs, please edit the question with a more detailed description of what you want to do with the edit.

Comment: There is absolutely zero chance that a beginner without a clue can implement such a complex widget as `QPlainTextEdit`. Forget it.